# different results for two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Query 1 :

```
SELECT  
                SUM(aol_int) AS AOL,
                SUM(android_phone_int) AS Android_Phone,
                SUM(androidTablet_int) AS Android_Tablet,
                SUM(apple_mail_int) AS Apple_Mail,
                SUM(blackberry_int) AS Blackberry,
                SUM(Eudora_int) AS Eudora,
                SUM(gmail_int) AS Gmail,
                SUM(hotmail_int) AS Hotmail,
                SUM(lotus_notes_int) AS Lotus_Notes,
                SUM(other_int) AS Other,
                SUM(other_webmail_int) as Other_Web_Mail,
                SUM(Outlook_int) AS Outlook,
                SUM(Postbox_int) AS Postbox,
                SUM(sparrow_int) AS Sparrow,
                SUM(thunderbird_int) AS Thunderbird,
                SUM(windowsLiveMail_int) AS Windows_Live_Mail,
                SUM(yahoo_int) AS Yahoo,
                SUM(iPad_int) AS iPad,
                SUM(iPhone_int) AS iPhone,
                SUM(iPod_int) AS iPod

       FROM    mytable;


Query 2: 

select sum(aol_int + android_phone_int + androidtablet_int+apple_mail_int+blackberry_int+Eudora_int+gmail_int+hotmail_int+lotus_notes_int+other_int+other_webmail_int+Outlook_int+Postbox_int+sparrow_int+thunderbird_int+windowsLiveMail_int+yahoo_int+iPad_int+iPhone_int+iPod_int) 
as total_percentage

FROM mytable;
```

When I am summing up the results of Query 1 I am getting different sum as compared to what I am getting via Query2. The value in Query2 is less than Query 1. Why is it like that?

**TROUBLESHOOTING:**

I tried to write my query like this:

```
SELECT SUM( ISNULL(aol_int,0)           + 
            ISNULL(android_phone_int,0) + 
            ISNULL(androidtablet_int,0) +
            ISNULL(apple_mail_int,0)    + 
            ISNULL(blackberry_int,0)    + 
            ISNULL(Eudora_int,0)        +
            ISNULL(gmail_int,0)         +
            ISNULL(hotmail_int,0)       +
            ISNULL(lotus_notes_int,0)   +
            ISNULL(other_int,0)         +
            ISNULL(other_webmail_int,0) +
            ISNULL(Outlook_int,0)       +
            ISNULL(Postbox_int,0)       +
            ISNULL(sparrow_int,0)       +
            ISNULL(thunderbird_int,0)   +
            ISNULL(windowsLiveMail_int,0)+
            ISNULL(yahoo_int,0)         +
            ISNULL(iPad_int,0)          +
            ISNULL(iPhone_int,0)        +
            ISNULL(iPod_int,0) )AS total_percentage

FROM mytable;
```

However, I am getting an error after running above query in the MySQL workbench:

Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'. What is wrong  here?

Comment: Retrieve all the numbers and calculate manually

Comment: What are the data types of all of these columns?  And/or do any contain NULL?

Answer (score 2):

This could happen if some columns in some of the rows contain `null`s. When this happens, all columns in a row with even a single `null` column would produce `null` in the chain of additions, so the row will add nothing to the total.

Here is a short demo of this effect. Setup:

```
create table test(x int null, y int null);
insert into test(x,y) values (1,null);
insert into test(x,y) values (null,2);
insert into test(x,y) values (3,3);
```

Queries:

```
select sum(x+y) from test;     -- Shows 6

select sum(x)+sum(y) from test -- Shows 9
```

See this demo on sqlfiddle: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c3e54/2).

Comment: +1 Most likely answer to me, but also possible that the OP is using FLOATs.

Comment: What alternative approach should I use then to find the correct total?

Comment: @user3239126 Did you try adding up the sums, the way I did in the second example query?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, I got two different results.

Comment: @user3239126 Is one of these results correct, or are both of them incorrect?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight One is correct corresponding to your `select sum(x)+sum(y) from test` query. I added each sum manually  and then compared it with the other query result which came out to be different.

Comment: @user3239126 I guess you have a solution then, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not really because, I want to use other approach which doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: @user3239126 Using `coalesce` instead of `isnull` will fix the probmem ([another demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c3e54/4)).